# Unity WebGL Simple JSON

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am trying to import text in my Unity script with WebGL but it seems like in WebGL, it is not able to find the JSON file itself. I have saved the file in StreamingAssets. How do I fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using SimpleJSON;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ReadScene : MonoBehaviour {
    public string jsonFile;
    JSONNode itemsData;
    string path;

    public Text sceneText;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {

        path = Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Settings.json");
        if (File.Exists (path)) {
            jsonFile = File.ReadAllText (path);
            DeserializePages ();
        } else {
            sceneText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }


    public void DeserializePages () {
        itemsData = JSON.Parse (jsonFile);
        var parseJSON = JSON.Parse (jsonFile);

        sceneText.text = parseJSON["Scene01"].Value;

    }


}
```

Also I have tried to change the folder location to "Resources" and still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html)

> It is not possible to access the `StreamingAssets` folder on WebGL and Android platforms. No file access is available on WebGL. Android uses a compressed `.apk` file. These platforms return a URL. Use the [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) class to access the Assets.

tbh I don't even know right now whether this `No file access is available on WebGL` is just misleading or indeed means there is no way to access `StreamingAssets`. I will assume it is just formulated badly and just means you can not access any file/directory directly but you can still go through [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) like

```
IEnumerator Start () 
{
    sceneText.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Settings.json");

    using(var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(path))
    {
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if(!request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error: " + result.error);
            yield break;
        }
       
        jsonFile = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
        DeserializePages();
    }
}

private void DeserializePages() 
{
    itemsData = JSON.Parse (jsonFile);

    sceneText.text = itemsData["Scene01"].Value;
    sceneText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```